# Beginner: Limit URL parameter by using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, routes

I need some help with a regular expression to limit the choices a user has for passing a crappy parameter for input.

For example the path looks like this:

`/project/create/:category` (:category is a placeholder for a parameter so I can access it in my controller)

Basically what I want to do is match the URL to one of 2 choices (offer|request) for the category. This makes any other path a user attempts do a 404 redirect, which works fine.

What would the regex need to be to only allow these choices? *(offer|request)*

`'/\/component\/create\/(offer|request)/'` - would do the trick right?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you phrased your question, what you have looks good. Couldn't you open a PHP shell and try it out, though?

Comment: Thanks If this is the way to it then I am happy with my progress of learning regex. Its something very new to me regex.